# For each combination of k from N items. Say "Yes", with probability p. How?

Tags: probability, combinations

I'm considering two ways of generating a random instance of the Yes's:-

> (a) For each combination of k items from N:
>
> ```
>      if a random value > p then say "Yes" for this combination.
> ```

and

> (b) Repeat Q times:
>
> ```
>     Randomly select k different items from the set of N,
>       then say "Yes" for this combination.
>
> Here, the probability of one or more Yes's is p.
> ```

---

The problem with (a) is when N very high,
there are lots of combinations to go through even if p is very low.

The problem with (b) is the maths is harder,
and as p approaches 1.0 then Q approaches infinity.

So I am going to use both methods. Then use maths to decide which one to use when the values N, k and p are given.

---

eg Select 2 items from 4. For each combination, 
the probability of a Yes is 0.3.

(a) There are 6 possible selections.
For each possible selection,
Think of a (random) number between 0.0 and 1.0,
if the number is 0.3 or below then Yes.

```
if bernoulli(0.3) then "Yes"
```

This gives me 6 Yes/No answers.

eg one possible sequence is "Yes", "No, "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"

(b) is more troublesome. I expect

```
p*(N)
  (k)
```

ie 0.3*6 = 1.8, Yes's.
Q could be from 0 to 6, (or even higher taking repeats into account), so I want a way of generating Q randomly to get the Yes's.

eg Select combinations 1, 3, and 4, and say "Yes" for each combination. The probability of this combination should be the same as the probability of the sequence in method (a).

This is not going through all combinations. So for a high N and low probability it will save time. eg N=1,000,000 and p = 0.1, randomly select 100,000 combinations.

---

1) Q is a function of N,k,p and a random number from 0.0 to 1.0,
What is this function?

Q = f1(N,k,p)
returning an integer 0 .. infinity.

2) Given N,k,p (and a certainty?), would it be best to use method (a) or (b), i.e. the number of combinations < Q?

f2(N,k,p, certainty)
returning the choice, (a) or (b), as a boolean.

---

Notes: Just starting with k=2 to make it easier.

Using a rational approximation to the inverse normal cumulative distribution function, incdf (by Peter John Acklam).

So given a random value in [0..1] this gives a normally distributed random value.
So to get the mean expected by method (a):-

```
number of possible choices (k=2), c = N*(N-1)/2

mean, m = p*c
```

and to get the same variance as method (a):-

```
s2 = sqrt(m*(1-p))
```

This gives a method of calculating Q:-

```
Q = m + s2*incdf(r), when r is a random value in (0..1)
```

But there is still the problem of collisions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Collision_counting so it would be better to increase Q by the expected number of collisions. Expected collision count, cc, is given by

$\sum_{k=1}^n q(k-1;d) = n - d + d \left (\frac {d-1} {d} \right )^n$, i.e.

```
cc = Q - c + c*pow((c-1)/c,Q)
```

So increase Q by cc. (Not sure whether to floor Q before doing this eq'n (if Q is < 1 then cc can be negative). Or to floor cc before adding it to Q.) Some of these would also collide with existing choices and with themselves. This means some more would have to be added... So I need a function which will give Q when all these are added together.

So for a first approximation:-

```
Q = Q + cc
```

Comment: It isn't really clear what you want as a result. Do you want a random string of `yes`s and `no`s?

Comment: Method (a) generates Yes/No for each combination. Method (b) saves time by only generating the combinations for which Yes is the answer.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to randomly select some number of combinations of items, where the probability of selecting each one combination is $p$?

Comment: I am selecting every combination, and assigning "Yes" or "No" to a each combination. For a given combination the probability of "Yes" is p. (Method (b) is another way of doing the same thing.)

Comment: But method b is not well defined. What is the value of Q?

Comment: Q is what I want to calculate, question (1). eg in the above example the function would most probably make Q = 2, but Q is random it depends on N,k and p.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21433/discussion-between-quentinuk-and-5xum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question:

$Q$ is the number of times you will say yes. You are saying either yes or no for each combination of $k$ items of a set of $n$ items, meaning you will have, in general, a stream of $N={n\choose k}$ yes and nos. $Q$ will take one of the values between $0$ and $N$, and since it is really just the number of succesful trials among $N$ attempts, it will follow a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), i.e.

$$P(Q=i) = {N\choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$

For the second question:

The second method is better than the first. It requires you to sample the binomial distribution, something any self-respecting programming language should be able to do quite quickly. After you sample, provided that $p$ isn't too big, the value of $Q$ will probably be smaller than $N$ (for $p=\frac12$, it will be, on average, equal to $\frac N2$), meaning you will not have to generate all of the subsets.

**Edit**:

Now I see what you mean. In method (b), you should, in the second step, create $Q$ distinct combinations of $k$ items. You can do this, but you need to be smart. For example, the following algorithm (in quasipython) is bad if $p$ is close to $1$:

```
sequences = []
while len(number_of_generated_subsequences) < Q:
    new_sequence = generate_new_subsequence()
    if new_sequence not in sequences:
        sequences.append(new_sequence)
```

What you want is a function which will select $Q$ different subsequences and they will all be different and equally likely. To do that, I suggest you enumerate all the possible subsequences in some clever way. (i.e, for $n=5$ and $k=3$, you can have the enumeration:

```
0: item1, item2, item3
1: item1, item2, item4
2: item1, item2, item5
3: item1, item3, item4
4: item1, item3, item5
5: item1, item4, item5
6: item2, item3, item4
7: item2, item3, item5
8: item2, item4, item5
9: item3, item4, item5
```

Now, all you need to do is select $Q$ distinct numbers out of the set $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ which, in Python, you can:

```
import random
random.sample(xrange(10), Q)
```

(note that `xrange` does not actually generate all the numbers, thus conserving space)

Using these tricks, you can easily implement a method that will be better than (a) no matter the value of $p$.

Comment: That's the wrong way round. eg if p = 1 then Q = infinity.

Comment: @QuentinUK No, if $p=1$, then $Q=N$, because you say yes to *each* combination of $k$ items out of $n$, and there are ${n\choose k}$ such combinations. Why would $Q$ be infinity?

Comment: because if p=1 then the random production of combinations must produce all combinations. Since they are generated randomly some may never occur. That's why there is question (2).

Comment: @QuentinUK Yes, it will produce *all* combinations, and there are $N$ of them, so $Q$, since it is equal to the number of combinations produced, is equal to $N$.

Comment: (b) could produce combination 1, then combination 1, then combination 1 ad infinitum. So for p approaching 1.0 method (a) should be used.

Comment: For the second question, if N = 1,000,000 and p is 5 in a million: Then Q would be most likely 5. But (a) would require going through a million combinations. So (b) would be the best method.

Comment: @QuentinUK I edited my answer quite a lot. Please read the edit as it, I think, answers your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21434/discussion-between-quentinuk-and-5xum).

Comment: @QuentinUK Because the chat does not support latex, I suggest we continue our discussion here.

Comment: OK. That is method (a) with storage. If storage is added to method (b) there is still the problem of what is Q? Q could be 0..N, it depends on p etc. eg with 10 combinations and p=0.1, Q is most likely 1, but it would sometimes be 0 and sometimes 10.

Comment: @QuentinUK as I already said, you must first set $Q$ by randomly sampling the binomial distribution mentioned in my answered. So, method (b) has two steps: first, generate a random value of $Q$. Then, select $Q$ subsets of $k$ elements out of $n$ elements. This is *not* method (a) with storage.

Comment: I do not know how to randomly sample a binomial distribution. Can you explain that please.

Comment: @QuentinUK: Follow this link: http://bit.ly/17XgEbm

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. ps I'm using Javascript. But http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/distributions/binomial.html has got a Javascript function. (Revealed by viewing the source.) So I'll try that.

Comment: @QuentinUK Good idea. I have no idea how to do statistics in javascript, but if you encounter problems, stackoverflow will probably be a better place to ask about them.